# How to iterate or map over a Ruby Hash to change one specific value?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, iteration

Is there a way iterate or map over the hash below so that you can add the deposit variable to the value 0 of the "john"=>0 key/value pair?

I commented the desired output below.

```
deposit = 20


Hash = {"Mike"=>0, "John"=>0, "Jen"=>0}


# I would like the result to look like Hash = {"Mike"=>0, "John"=>20, "Jen"=>0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your constant name `Hash` will mess up many things. Understanding that,

```
Hash["John"] += deposit
```